# How to customize Django inline admin forms based on the object instance

Tags: python, django

The Django documentation makes it clear how to customize ModelForm instances based on the attributes of the particular Model instance being edited. However, I am working with a design that involves a lot of foreign key relationships between models, and I keep running into situations where I would like to modify a particular inline form instance based on the inline Model associated with it. I have dug through the documentation and the code, but the solution for this is eluding me.

The closest thing to a hook for this that I've been able to find is InlineModelAdmin.get_formset(), but the object instance that gets passed to that method is the parent object, not an instance of the child object. My instinct is that there is a way to do this, though. Does anybody know the proper way?

Comment: I suppose that you can set a `ModelForm` in the `InlineModelAdmin.get_formset()` and customize this form based on `instance` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not 100% sure I fully understand what you are asking, but you can specify a `forms.ModelForm` for the admin inline (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.form) and that receives an `instance` of the current inline object and then you can change the form fields based on the `instance`.

Comment: There we go, that is the piece that I was missing: I wasn't thinking about performing this customization in the `forms.ModelForm`'s __init__() method. Thanks!